# Can't create migration because test projects won't build, even though main project can?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Before fixing tests I would like to fix the main codebase with some migrations.

Entity Framework won't let me use `Add-Migration` if some projects don't build in the solution (i.e., the test projects). The rest of the solution, however, is able to build and launch.

Is there a way I can ignore the test projects (but without resorting to e.g. commenting out the tests or removing the projects)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Add-Migration` should work only with built assembly. For this reason, tests are not (or shouldn't be) the part of the final executable assembly -> that's the reason why new Project for test is always created.

Maybe it will help you to set for `Add-Migration` the parametes where you specify, which project should be use to find the `DbContext` - `[-ProjectName <String>]` / `[-StartUpProjectName <String>]`. From this project (and from any related) there shouldn't be reference to Test projects. If it is, something is probably wrong about the concept.

```
PM> get-help add-migration

NAME
    Add-Migration
    
SYNOPSIS
    Scaffolds a migration script for any pending model changes.
    
    
SYNTAX
    Add-Migration [-Name] <String> [-Force] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] 
        [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>]     [-ConnectionStringName <String>] [-IgnoreChanges] 
        [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
    
    Add-Migration [-Name] <String> [-Force] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] 
        [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] -ConnectionString <String> -ConnectionProviderName <String>
        [-IgnoreChanges] [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```